# Apache ANT built not changing class files when changing source

Tags: java, ant, compilation

Apache ANT built not showing the errors and  is not generating modified class files upon modifying source

Comment: Have you tried a "clean" first?

Answer (score 2):

```
1. Do a clean first.(make sure its deleting ) the class files.
2. Make sure that ant complile task include the src directory you are modifying.
```